# Changing the vertical location of an Header in Sejda

Tags: batch-processing, pdf-manipulation, sejda

I am using sejda-console-1.0.0.RELEASE to apply a Header to a PDF-file.
Now i would like to change the vertical position of the Header, i.e. move it 
2 cm futher down. I tried forcing a new line by adding blank spaces, but that doesn't work.

How can i do this ?

Comment: I'm afraid there's no option to specify a top margin when applying a header.

Can I ask more details about your use-case? Why is the default header location not suitable?

Comment: The PDFs i want to apply the Header to, have the company logo in the upper left  corner. I wanted to allign the header in the upper right corner with the bottom of that logo.